# Media files usage

Tags: html, css

i am trying to learn web development and now i have a question that i would like to get an answer.
It is right to use media in 2 different css files instead of making always @media...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 1023px)" href="../scss/mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="../scss/style.css" />
```

This will load the proper css file depending on your device.
Please tell me if that is right and good to use.
Thank you.

Comment: making external CSS files for best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1. Create multiple CSS files, each with their own media type (How you have it in your example)
2. Create one CSS file and place multiple @media declarations within it.

One can argue which one is better and why, so I’ll just talk a bit about each and let you decide.

Creating multiple files will slow down your site since more HTTP requests are made. Creating multiple files can also be hard to work with since you have to keep constantly switching tabs.

Creating one file can speed up your site since fewer requests are made, but can be difficult to work with if you have a lot of CSS.

You can always switch from one to the other later, but my recommendation is to use one file. The final choice however, is yours

Comment: But my site will request just 1 css file if the device by ex is smaller then 600px and i have two css files for each device.

Comment: It's up to you then. I was assuming you had more CSS files than what you have shown. Making them two files if fine, it that is easier for you to manage. It really is what is best for you.